# using server code to change color of selected tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some `a` tags .

```
<ul class="" data-persist="true" >
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li>
     <a class="tagactive" href="~/Product/ProductExplain?IdGroup=@item.id_tblgroup&flag=2&idproduct=@item.id">@item.explain </a>
   </li>
}
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on any tag I want its color to change to red, of course after posting the page.

How can I send the selected link to the server and return it to change its color?

**style.css**

```
.tagactive{
     color:red;
}
```

Comment: You need additional data in your view model. Just add a property `IsActive` and set it to true when you want to change the color. You can then check it in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Tanner , please **do not** send newbies to w3schools. That site is considered to be harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You can have property in `model` as `SelectedTag`. Set value for this Propery on Controller side, depending on this value you can Set class as below

```
<ul class="" data-persist="true" >
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li>
     <a class="@if (Model.SelectedTag== Item.Name) {<text>tagactive</text>}
               else {<text>taginactive</text>}"
     href="~/Product/ProductExplain?IdGroup=@item.id_tblgroup&flag=2&idproduct=@item.id">@item.explain </a>
   </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: how can i fill Model.SelectedTag in view ?

Comment: I said you need to pass value from controller to view

Answer (score 0):

You could try JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .MyRed {
        color: red
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="myId"></div>

       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="MyRed">google.com </a></br>
               <a href="#">test.com </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("a").click(function()
                {
                    $("a").removeClass("MyRed");
                    $(this).addClass("MyRed");
                });

                //  $("a").removeClass
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is saying he is posting the page!